# How to PNGCrush on directories in Linux (Mint/Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, pngcrush

I have a directory tree with many image files and I have to move then for another directory tree. But in this destiny directory my png files must be compressed.

For instance:

Soure directory tree:

```
./model/layout/img
./model/layout/img/log
./model/layout/img/errs
./model/layout/img/commons
```

(With many type of images files)

Destinty directorey tree:

```
./app/img
./app/img/log
./app/img/errs
./app/img/commons
```

Does anyone has solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this site. https://davidwalsh.name/pngcrush-directory.

I just have to modify a little bit the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

SRC_DIR=./model/layout/img/
DST_DIR=./app/img/

rm -rf $DST_DIR
cp -R  $SRC_DIR $DST_DIR

for png in `find $DST_DIR -name "*.png"`;
do
    echo "crushing $png"    
    pngcrush -reduce -brute "$png" temp.png

    mv -f temp.png $png
done;
```